# phonetic spelling in Python and Java

Tags: java, python, text-processing, text-mining, spelling

I am trying to build a system that accepts text and outputs the phonetic spelling of the words of this text. Any ideas on what libraries can be used in Python and Java?

Answer (score 3):

Check out soundex

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Comment: Great answer(never knew about this)!  I did a search and found this question that has an example of a python implementation of soundex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562438/could-use-some-help-with-this-soundex-coding

Comment: I am looking more to obtaining the corresponding phonetic alphabet in text form.

Answer (score 2):

I came across an old python package [Raze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/raze/). It includes a phonetic module with a translation api:

```
>>> pd = PhoneticDictionary()
>>> pd.spell('Hello world')
... hotel-echo-lima-lima-oscar whiskey-oscar-romeo-lima-delta
```

It hasn't been updated in a while, but it still works.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something akin to the international phonetic alphabet (IPA) or some other phonetic output? If ARPAbet is ok, there is the CMU pronouncing dictionary (http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict). That'll give the ARPAbet rendering of most words in English. I've written some code that converts the ARPAbet spelling to IPA and post to github if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this : http://texttophonetic.appspot.com/

This tool can help you translate english to IPA (to phonetic). You might want to write some code to get the result then save to your database.